# Gumble distribution probability

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

If I want to find y such that P(Y< y)=0.999 of Gumbel Distribution with
a=30.134711, b= 7.621868. 
where $$f(y\,;a,b)=\frac{1}{b}\exp\left[-\frac{(y-a)}{b}-e^{-(y-a)/b}\right]\quad,\,y\in\mathbb R\quad,\,a\in\mathbb R,b>0$$

Is it correct that I use quantile of Gumbel distribution with p=0.999 to find such y which is =82.7809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct

From that density, you have $$\mathbb P(Y \le y)=F(y)= \exp(-\exp(-(y-a)/b))$$

and inverting this gives $$F^{-1}(p)= a-b\log_e(-\log_e(p))$$

then substituting $a=30.134711, b= 7.621868,  p=0.999$ gives about $y=82.7809$

Comment: Thank you sir.Another question follow from that is this equivalent to that “estimate the daily rainfall total that will be exceeded at least once in 2019 with probability 0.001”